# Pyinstaller Output file not working at all

Tags: python, windows, pyinstaller

Here I have a basic main.py file that I'm testing pyinstaller on to see if I can get it working:

```
import tkinter as tk

root= tk.Tk()

canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width = 300, height = 300)
canvas1.pack()

def hello ():  
    label1 = tk.Label(root, text= 'Hello World!', fg='green', font=('helvetica', 12, 'bold'))
    canvas1.create_window(150, 200, window=label1)
    
button1 = tk.Button(text='Click Me',command=hello, bg='brown',fg='white')
canvas1.create_window(150, 150, window=button1)

root.mainloop()
```

I'm trying to compile it to an executable with a command like: `pyinstaller --onefile -w main.py`. This creates the file in the `dist` folder without a problem, however when I try to run the file it gets blocked and deleted by windows defender, saying it's a virus or "potentially harmful". When I turn off windows defender it tries to run but has a generic "This script failed to run" error. Does anyone have any ideas why the script is failing to run, and if that's not causing the defender error, what could be causing that as well?